# left_join (dplyr) the next available date

Tags: r, join, merge, dplyr, left-join

I have 2 datasets in "R".

The first DB contains specific dates:

```
    Value       Date   
#   20          2017-10-19 
#   19          2017-10-23 
#   19          2017-11-03 
#   20          2017-11-10
```

And the second contains the level of an stock index from the last 5 years

```
     Date       Index
#    2017-11-10 13.206,35
#    2017-11-03 13.378,96
#    2017-10-25 13.404,58
#    2017-10-19 13.517,98
```

Now I want to merge by searching for the dates from the first dataset "DB" and adding the correct Index value for this date from the second dataset "Hist".

What I did is using the left_join function:

```
DB <- left_join(DB, Hist, by = "Date")
```

The problem is some dates in the first dataset are public holidays where no data is available in the second dataset "Hist". So I have some "NA".

```
  Value   Date         Index
# 20      2017-10-19   13.517,98
# 19      2017-10-23   NA
# 19      2017-11-03   13.378,96
# 20      2017-11-10   13.206,35
```

What I'm looking for is to take the value of the next available date instead of adding NA.

Example: Instead of adding NA taking the index of 2017-10-25 (2 days later)

```
  Value   Date         Index
# 20      2017-10-19   13.517,98
# 19      2017-10-23   13.404,58
# 19      2017-11-03   13.378,96
# 20      2017-11-10   13.206,35
```

Has anybody an idea. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Original Request

The following is an option. It uses `full_join`, and then the `fill` function to impute the missing value.

```
library(tidyverse)

DB_final <- DB %>%
  full_join(Hist, by = "Date") %>%
  arrange(Date) %>%
  fill(Index, .direction = "up") %>%
  filter(!is.na(Value))
DB_final
#   Value       Date     Index
# 1    20 2017-10-19 13.517,98
# 2    19 2017-10-23 13.404,58
# 3    19 2017-11-03 13.378,96
# 4    20 2017-11-10 13.206,35
```

However, the user needs to know the fill direction (`up` or `down`) in advance. It may not be useful if the user does not know that.

#### Impute Missing Value based on the Nearest Date

Here is another option, which I think is more robust. It will impute the missing value use the `Index` from the nearest date.

#### Step 1: Find the Nearest Date

```
# Collect all dates
Date_vec <- sort(unique(c(DB$Date, Hist$Date)))

# Create a distance matrix based on dates than convert to a data frame
dt <- Date_vec %>%
  dist() %>%
  as.matrix() %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  rowid_to_column(var = "ID") %>%
  gather(ID2, Value, -ID) %>%
  mutate(ID2 = as.integer(ID2)) %>%
  filter(ID != ID2) %>%
  arrange(ID, Value) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  select(-Value)

dt$ID <- Date_vec[dt$ID]
dt$ID2 <- Date_vec[dt$ID2]  

names(dt) <- c("Date1", "Date2")

dt
# # A tibble: 5 x 2
# # Groups:   ID [5]
#       Date1      Date2
#      <date>     <date>
# 1 2017-10-19 2017-10-23
# 2 2017-10-23 2017-10-25
# 3 2017-10-25 2017-10-23
# 4 2017-11-03 2017-11-10
# 5 2017-11-10 2017-11-03
```

`dt` shows the nearest date of all the dates.

#### Step 2: Perform multiple join

Join `DB` and `dt`, and then join `Hist` twice based on different date columns.

```
DB2 <- DB %>% left_join(dt, by = c("Date" = "Date1")) 

DB3 <- DB2 %>%
  left_join(Hist, by = "Date") %>%
  left_join(Hist, by = c("Date2" = "Date")) 
DB3
#   Value       Date      Date2   Index.x   Index.y
# 1    20 2017-10-19 2017-10-23 13.517,98      <NA>
# 2    19 2017-10-23 2017-10-25      <NA> 13.404,58
# 3    19 2017-11-03 2017-11-10 13.378,96 13.206,35
# 4    20 2017-11-10 2017-11-03 13.206,35 13.378,96
```

#### Step 3: Finalize the Index

If there are values in `Index.x`, use that, otherwise, use the values in `Index.y`.

```
DB4 <- DB3 %>% 
  mutate(Index = ifelse(is.na(Index.x), Index.y, Index.x)) %>%
  select(Value, Date, Index)
DB4
#   Value       Date     Index
# 1    20 2017-10-19 13.517,98
# 2    19 2017-10-23 13.404,58
# 3    19 2017-11-03 13.378,96
# 4    20 2017-11-10 13.206,35
```

`DB4` is the final output.

**DATA**

```
DB <- structure(list(Value = c(20L, 19L, 19L, 20L), Date = structure(c(17458, 
                                                                       17462, 17473, 17480), class = "Date")), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("Value", 
                                                                                                                                                "Date"), row.names = c(NA, -4L))


Hist <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(17480, 17473, 17464, 17458), class = "Date"), 
                       Index = c("13.206,35", "13.378,96", "13.404,58", "13.517,98"
                       )), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("Date", "Index"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                            -4L))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Already your first option fulfills my need since I know the direction. And this is pretty slim code. Great, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A solution could be

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

clean_df <- function(df) {

  ix <- which(is.na(df$Index))
  df$Index[ix] <- df$Index[ix + 1]

  filter(df, !is.na(.data$Value))

}

full_join(DB, Hist) %>%
  arrange(Date) %>%
  clean_df()
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have done, plus as.Date() to format dates:

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

DB = data.table(
  Value = c(20,19,19,29),
  Date = c("2017-10-19","2017-10-23","2017-11-03","2017-11-10")
  )

Hist = data.table(
  Date = c("2017-11-10","2017-11-03","2017-10-25","2017-10-19"),
  Index = c("13.206,35","13.378,96","13.404,58","13.517,98")
  )

DB[, Date := as.Date(Date)]
Hist[, Date := as.Date(Date)]

DB <- left_join(DB,Hist,by="Date") %>% as.data.table()
```

Now perform the steps below:

```
# Get rows which are missing an Index.
DB_na <- DB[is.na(Index),]
DB <- DB[!is.na(Index),]

# Build function to find appropriate Index, given an na_date.
get_na_index <- function(na_date) {
  bigger_dates = DB[Date>na_date,]
  index = bigger_dates[which.min(other_dates-na_date), Index]
  return(index)
}

# Use apply() to perform row-wise operation.
DB_na$Index <- apply(matrix(DB_na$Date), 1, get_na_index)

# Combine rows
DB <- rbind(DB, DB_na) %>% arrange(Date)
```

The Output:

```
DB

  Value       Date     Index
1    20 2017-10-19 13.517,98
2    19 2017-10-23 13.378,96
3    19 2017-11-03 13.378,96
4    29 2017-11-10 13.206,35
```

Comment: Thanks, this works but is not solving my problem. Because it seems that it takes the next index value of the joint "DB". I want to search for the next Index value in "Hist" if NA.